# Обработка нажатия кнопки в yii

Tags: yii

Нужно сгенерировать несколько кнопок (голос к посту + или -) на странице и собственно обработать их нажатия. Как обрабатывать нажатия кнопок в yii и задавать им имена?

П.С. Сорри за глупые вопросы. Просто гугл не помого.

Comment: Простите, а обрабатывать нажатие на клиенте или на сервере?

Comment: На сервере. Нужно по нажатию кнопки изменить значение в БД (+1 или -1 к посту). Соответсвенно, таких кнопок будет по 2 к каждому посту. Как мне узнать, что нажата кнопка и какая?

Comment: Гуглите на тему ``AJAX`` - почти всё, что найдете, будет о вашей задаче. Yii это или нет, не имеет значения.

Comment: Нет времени в AJAX пока разбираться((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну на самом деле есть клевая фишка в Yii

```
<div id="mposter">Обновить этот DIV</div>
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Получить ответ от сервера',
                                       CController::createUrl('/controller/action'), 
                                       array('type' => 'POST',// method
                                             'data'=>array('update'=>TRUE),// DATA
                                             'update' => '#mposter',// что обновить :)
                                              ));
                                        ?>

В итоге появится ссылка на странице, которая создаст Jquery обработчик,
```

вот фотки  1 -до нажатия по ссылке

[image: pic 1]

2 после нажатия

Ну и пишем в контроллере экшен и радуемся, добавляем поля и прочее.

[image: pic 2]

**//upd**

а еще в yii есть подмена ссылки :) выглядит так вот т.е. при наведении на ссылку будет левый адрес, но отправляться будет по нужному :) и firebug это покажет, но в любом случае постоянно проверять ссылки это гемор :)

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
  "Link Text",
  Yii::app()->createUrl( '/controller/ACTION' ),
  array( 'type' => 'POST',
    'beforeSend' => "function( request ) // можно спросить до отправки что-то или проверить данные какие-нибудь.
                     {
                       alert('Бла бла бла');
                     }",
    'success' => "function( data )
                  {
                    $('#mposter').html(data);// получили данные - обновили DIV
                  }",
    'data' => array( 'val1' => '1', 'val2' => '2' ), // посылаем значения
      'cache'=>'false' // если нужно можно закешировать

  ),
  array( // самое интересное
    'href' => Yii::app()->createUrl( 'ajax/opla-tra-ta-ta' ),// подменяет ссылку на левую
    'class' => "sadfsadfsadclass" // добавляем какой-нить класс для оформления
  )
);
```

Удачи :)

Comment: JS код в PHP? Имхо это пи**** :)

Comment: согласен с AlexWindHope ) Хоть и нравится мне Yii но JS код пишу ручками в js файле

Comment: А если вручную каждую кнопку сделать как отдельную форму и обрабатывать типа обычным файлом php (не в стиле yii) action.php?id=id_post. А в файле ation.php выполнять подключение к БД и изменять одно значение (id поста узнаю из GET). Это будет совсем плохо?

Comment: 2 @AlexWindHope ну на самом деле можно все вынести отдельно в файл и вызывать только функции JS это все просто удобно когда небольшие данные отправлять и принимать через Ajax. так что в принципе работает это нормально, пусть и немного может не "по понятиям".

2 @Андрей Бакша ну если уж столкнулся с Yii, то лучше и продолжить писать в его стиле, иначе это потом выльется в "говнокод" - а это вааще не айс

Comment: вот уж не думал, что это так сложно. думал, просто я нуб полнейший... придется видимо через ajax пихать это.

Comment: @Shrek - не можно а нужно ( если таки принцы делать именно так ). А еще лучше - ни в каком проявлении не пихать клиентскую логику в ПоХаПе... 

Как человек который когда-то работал с подобным месивом - я, мягко говоря, не приветствую подобный подход. И неважно как вы это делаете - читаете файл либо пишете ручками, с таким кодом работать страшно ( а если еще и не ты его писал, то вообще... )

Answer (score 0):

В-общем сделал почти как посоветовал [[@Shrek](/users/4597/shrek)](/users/4597/shrek). А именно:

ajax-кнопку:

```
     echo CHtml::ajaxButton('-',  
     CController::createUrl('/reviews_objects/vote_button'),   
     array('type' => 'POST',  
     'data'=>array('update'=>TRUE,  
     'id_review_object'=>$value['id_review_object'],//id поста  
     'type_vote'=>'minus'),//нажат голос минус  
      ));
```

и в экшене vote_button изменяю значение в БД.

Все работает, но хотелось бы, чтоб сразу обновлялось значение рядом - количество голосов. Иначе видно только после обновления страницы. Может подскажете как это сделать?
Вывожу кол-во голосов просто:

```
echo CHtml::encode($value['counter_minuses']);
```

$value - результат поиска в БД. Передан из контроллера в представление.

Comment: Вот там, где написано updat, идет #mposter, это id diva, который нужно обновить. Как обновить? В скрипте, где ты изменяешь значение, получи новое значение из БД и просто сделай echo значения и оно появится в dive mposter. Я же все написал в ответе.


    CController::createUrl('/controller/action'), 
      array('type' => 'POST',// method
      'data'=>array('update'=>TRUE),// DATA
      'update' => '#mposter',// что обновить :)
    ));

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже стоит задача с обновлением данных на странице в одном из разделов админки. Есть инфа о пользователе и кнопка "Активировать". При нажатии на кнопку в базе обновляется соответствующая информация (статус) и еще кнопка "Активировать" должна смениться на "Заблокировать". Вот это обновление кнопок у меня и не работает. Если я вставляю обе эти кнопки в контейнер <div id="data"></div> и указываю 'update'=>'#data', то вместо кнопки что-то похожее на текстовое поле, а в результате нажатия она вообще исчезает. Подскажите, как решить проблему